# Word 2011 for Mac: How to delete a Quick Style Set?

Tags: ms-office

Tryig to delete a quick style set from Word 2011 for Mac. This [link](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/word/item/cd8da9b1-833c-4035-8ab5-0e83a065a7f7) claims the styles are in "/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Style Set" and the save dialog seems to confirm that.

However if I try to go there with the Finder, there is no visible or hidden "Office" folder in the "Microsoft" folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me your question really is, "Where is the Office folder within Application Support/Microsoft?" It looks to me that once you find the correct folder, you'll have no trouble following the instructions for deleting a Quck Style Set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Mac expert, but I think I figured it out. I'm running Office 2011 on Mac OS X 10.9.5. I searched for the name of one of the other quick set styles to figure it out.

The quick set folder is located at: `/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Media/QuickStyles/`.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac OS X 10.5.8 system with Word 2008, I do indeed have a folder "/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/". I can get to it either with Finder or with the Terminal command-line.

You might want to double-check that you are in "/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/", and not the system-wide "/Library/Application Support/".  There is a "Microsoft" directory in both places, but they contain different things.